# Magento Multistore onepage checkout not working

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, multistore

My problem is , Onepage checkout is not working in multistore website.

In console i got this error:
POST http://www.domain.com/xx/index.php/onepage/json/saveBilling - 404 Not Found

But it is working in main website.

Could you please help me to solve this issue..

Answer (score 0):

please enable logs to see exact error in to your store.

You are missing the inline javascript code that defines the billing variable. Compare the billing.phtml files in your current theme against the ones in:

app\design\frontend\base\default\template\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml

app\design\frontend\base\default\template\persistent\checkout\onepage\billing.phtml
You should see similar to below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var billing = new Billing('co-billing-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/getAddress') ?>address/', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveBilling') ?>');
    var billingForm = new VarienForm('co-billing-form');

    //billingForm.setElementsRelation('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('directory/json/childRegion') ?>', '<?php echo $this->__('Select State/Province...') ?>');
    $('billing-address-select') && billing.newAddress(!$('billing-address-select').value);

    var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'billing:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'billing:postcode');
//]]>
</script>
```

i will help you out. send me admin credential to tuufail@hotmail.com

Comment: may be  its javascript error. disable javascript  if you are using any 3rd party plugin for onepage checkout